# 301 redirection in htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web-hosting

I have and issue when I'm trying to redirect my old domain to my new domain. Things look like that right now:
newdomain.pl <- is connected to blogger account
olddomain.pl <- is connected to server with .htaccess file (before it was connected to blogger account)
I would like it to work like that : olddomain.pl/subdomain -> redirect to newdomain.pl/subdomain. But whatever I try to put into my .htaccess file it's redirecting my old site to main page of newdomain (newdomain.pl). I've tried codess like that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain.pl[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.pl/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

but it's also redirecting to main page of new domain. Only when I put:

```
RedirectRule / http://www.newdomain.pl
```

It's redirecting to http://www.newdomain.plsubdomain <- but there is slash "/"  missing between the newdomain name and subdomain. Unfortunately when I write this:

```
RedirectRule / http://www.newdomain.pl/
```

it's redirecting to main domain page http://www.newdomain.pl, so it's not working. I don't know what can be wrong, I'm fighting with that three days already. Does anyone have an idea where can be the problem? Maybe there is something wrong with hosting that I bought?
 Thank you in advance for any response
Regards, Pawel

Comment: in your `RewriteRule` you are redirecting from newdomain.pl to newdomain.pl

Comment: ok, you're right but i wrote that later I've tried to redirect diffrently by RedirectRule (without rewrite) and it also don't work.

Comment: So, all, what you need is to redirect from olddomain to newdomain ?

Comment: yes but including subdomains, so if someone will enter to my olddomain.pl/subdomain it should change address to newdomain.pl/subdomain but it's redirecting to newdomain.pl without subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

For only redirecting queries without direct redirecting to domain remove `R` flag.

Comment: I modified your code and it worked. I've put the answer above. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Amper Glad to help. Btw, you can set my answer as accepted. This would be great.

Comment: @Amper and also you don't need to define two rewrite rules. See my updated answer how to do it more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in olddomain/.htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1
```

Comment: I've tried this one as well and it's sending me to my main page as well. I've checked htaccess with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it showed me <br>  "This rule was met, the new url is http://www.olddomain.pl/subdomain"

Comment: 301 is a premanent redirect, so browser caches it, may be that is the Issue. clear your browser cache .

Comment: I'm clearing cache and all browser history after every change in htaccess

Comment: Where is your htaccess located?

Comment: Do you have any other rules or redirects in .htaccess?

Comment: Solved. I've putted the answer above. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution. The problem was not including "www" in RewriteRule. When I changed it, it worked. I'm putting the code that worked for me below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.pl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.pl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.pl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.pl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thank you everyone!